# Content-Disposition: inline do not work in Chrome?

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome

I am sending pdf file from my ASP.NET app with header below to display pdf file inside browser. Everything works fine on IE and FF but not on Chrome. I get blank web page and no PDF file is displayed. Is this known issue?

```
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="myfile.pdf"
```

Comment: Have you set `Content-type: application/pdf`?

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by the `Adobe plugin`. Goto `chrome://plugins/` and try disabling it.